# Working with temporary session data with Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, session, redis

I have read that default session storage for asp.net applications is memory.

I came to Asp.Net from php and I don't have much experience with how .Net is working with sessions. For example php is termitating process each time rhe request ends and it's default mechanism is to store session data in system files on disk.

The question is whether the problem exists if I need to update my application on production server almost every day with restarting the process
(Running with Kestrel behind Nginx). Does it mean that all users will log out when it happens?

If so, how difficult is it to use PostgreSQL database to store session data (with Entity Framework)? Or there are no options but to add Redis storage to my application?

Answer (score 2):

1) ASP.NET has several Session-State Modes.
Please read their percise description here: 
[Session-State Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)

2) If you use default in-proc mode, restarting the server or modifying web config file will drop the existing sessions

3)  To store session state in PostgreSQL you will have to find or implement custom Session State Provider

There is [existing open source implementation](https://github.com/dnauck/AspSQLProvider)
which can be installed through nuget.

Also you may consider instructions regarding [Implementing a Session-State Store Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx)